# Grammar question in prayer

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk

Why in the prayer:

יי עז לעמו יתן , יי יברך את-עמו בשלום

is the word יברך followed by את,? Both יברך & יתן are forms of a verb. Does anyone have any sources that address this grammar sentence structure?

Comment: The quoted line is Psalms 29:11

Comment: What is confusing you about the את? Do you also expect it elsewhere or do you not expect it in this spot? What do you know about this word? Help us help you.

Comment: Most verbs have את after from what I understand. The sentence structure makes that impossible in the יברך verse, but I am just curious if anyone has come across any commentary on this odd sentence structure.

Comment: Are you wondering why the first part of the line isn't structured like the sentence in Shoftim 9:29 ":שופטים פרק ט
 וּמִי יִתֵּן אֶת הָעָם הַזֶּה בְּיָדִי"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am also wondering if this may fall under מעשה’ מרכבה?‘

Comment: @DoubleAA Should we retag the question? This way it's somewhat misleading and hard to find...

Comment: Grammar is not מעשה מרכבה.

Comment: @N.T. I disagree. In my Koren Siddur there is an interesting passage right before ברכו את יי and the שמע in קבלת שבת. The paragraph is in Aramaic and it explains that the את in ברכו את יי is referring to the eve of Shabbat. Seems pretty מעשה מרכבה to me, especially due to the fact that taken in this context it makes absolutely zero sense.

Comment: מעשה מרכבה is much more specific than mysticism and Kabbalah in general. It refers specifically to the explanation of the vision at the beginning of Ezekiel.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen in [this Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%AA#Hebrew), the preposition את is

> [u]sed to introduce a semantically definite direct object.

The first clause (ה' עוז לעמו יתן) contains no definite direct object (the direct object עוז (strength) is not semantically definite) and thus there is no need for את.

The second clause (ה' יברך את עמו בשלום) does contain a definite direct object - the semantically definite עמו (His people) is the direct object of the verb יברך (He will bless). Therefore, it is preceded by את.